# Rails - Yield a Partial in a Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I think this is a very simple problem and I could be just going about it incorrectly because I am new to rails, but here it goes......

What I want to do is render the results of my partial view in my application layout using a yield. I have a search bar at the top of my page that I want the results to display in the yield in the layout.  Again, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do this, so if it isn't, just let me know the best way.

Right now, I get a "Missing template events/search" error when I try and use the search on my page.  If I add the following code to controller it gets all of the information properly, but doesn't render in the application layout, it just displays the partial:

```
render :partial => "events/search_results"
```

Here is what the relevant section controller looks like:

```
layout "application"

def search
  @events = Event.search params[:search]
end
```

Here is the application layout (Please excuse the formatting, I tried to make it easily readable):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>XXXXXXX</title>
   <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"type="text/javascript"></script> <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-top">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
             <%= render :partial => "events/search" %>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span1">
            </br>
                <div class="well well-small">
                    <center><h3>Filters</h3></center> </br>
                    <%= render :partial => "events/left_severity_filter" %>
                    <%= render :partial => "events/left_date_filter" %>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="span8">
                         <%= yield %>
                    </div>
        <div class="span3">
                         <%= render :partial => "events/right_filter" %
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post your application layout, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the `events/search.html.erb` template in the views. Create this view template and it will be displayed where the `yield` is.